# unregistering event handler

Tags: c#, events

I have a class that can raise events when some message is received. In addition it can also subscribe to messages from other instances of the same class. (See shortened class below.) I'm having trouble unregistering event handlers...
When debugging I can see the Delegate.Remove being called (in an alternate syntax version), but nothing is removed from the invokation list...

```
class MyClass
{
    private event EventHandler<EventArgs> MessageReceived;

    public void SubscribeToMessages(Action<object, EventArgs> eventHandler)
    {
        this.MessageReceived += new EventHandler<EventArgs>(eventHandler);
    }

    public void UnsubscribeFromMessages(Action<object, EventArgs> eventHandler)
    {
        this.MessageReceived -= new EventHandler<EventArgs>(eventHandler);
    }

    private void MessageFromOtherObject_Received(object sender, EventArgs arg)
    {
    }

    public void StartListeningToObject(MyClass obj)
    {
        obj.SubscribeToMessages(MessageFromOtherObject_Received);
    }

    public void StopListeningToObject(MyClass obj)
    {
        obj.UnsubscribeFromMessages(MessageFromOtherObject_Received);
    }
}

void Test()
{
    MyClass mainObj = new MyClass();
    MyClass otherObj = new MyClss();

    mainObj.StartListeningToObject(otherObj);
    //...
    mainObj.StopListeningToObject(otherObj);
}
```

So on calling StopListentingToObject() I can see it attempt to remove the handler, but it remains, and event are still getting triggered on the mainObj...

Now from what I know and what I read the

```
this.MessageReceived -= new EventHandler<EventArgs>(eventHandler);
```

syntax should work just fine, yet it seems to think that that is somehow a different delegate apparently.

What do I do wrong???

Many thanks in adavance for any advice!

Comment: @chancea, that's not really true, it should work like this (at least from what I've read). The major difference is that if you store the event handler, when you unsubcribe, you're specific about it. If you use syntax with creating a new one and -=, then it unsubscribes the last one added.

Comment: @chancea No, you do not.  Delegates override their equality semantics; different delegates pointing to the same object instance and method are equal delegates.

Comment: have you tried using this `this.MessageReceived -= eventHandler;` ?

Comment: Yes. My understanding also was/is that  creating a new EventHandler is not a problem as Delegate.Combine and Delegate.Remove should normally look at the encapsulated method instead...

Comment: @dotctor Yes, I did. But I get an error message underlining the "eventHandler" saying: Cannot implicitely convert type 'System.Action<object,System.EventArgs>' to 'System.EventHandler<System.EventArgs>'

Comment: @bjavor Why is the method accepting a delegate of a different type in the first place?  And for that matter, why do you have that method in the first place?

Comment: @Servy Just did a small [test](http://ideone.com/PAmzty) and I stand corrected. (I am actually sitting in my desk chair though...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that your code is broken is because you created these two methods:

```
public void SubscribeToMessages(Action<object, EventArgs> eventHandler)
{
    this.MessageReceived += new EventHandler<EventArgs>(eventHandler);
}

public void UnsubscribeFromMessages(Action<object, EventArgs> eventHandler)
{
    this.MessageReceived -= new EventHandler<EventArgs>(eventHandler);
}
```

instead of just adding/removing handlers from the event (which is what you should do) you're actually doing something quite different.

`SubscribeToMessages` is adding an event handler which, when invoked, will call the `Invoke` method of the `eventHandler` delegate.

When you call `UnsubscribeFromMessages` you're trying to remove the handler who's body is a call to the `Invoke` method of the `eventHandler` instance you've been passed.  However, you're passing in different `Action` instances to each of these two method calls (even though those two different actions both point to the same method/object pair), so the event handlers you're trying to add/remove are each referring to different `Action` instances, and thus aren't considered equal.

If you just add/remove handlers to the event directly, instead of adding a second layer of indirection where you add an event handler that invokes an event handler that invokes the actual method, you'll be fine.

Alternatively, don't have the subscribe/unsubscribe methods that you are using have a different delegate than your event.  Have them accept delegates of the type of the actual event, so that you can simply add/remove them, which will also remove the extra layer of indirection.

Answer (score 0):

Why so overcomplicated? why do you need private event? Keep it simple!

```
    class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
    }

    void Test()
    {
        MyClass mainObj = new MyClass();
        MyClass otherObj = new MyClass();

        mainObj.StartListeningToObject(otherObj);
        //...
        mainObj.StopListeningToObject(otherObj);
    }
}
class MyClass
{
    public event EventHandler<EventArgs> MessageReceived;

    private void MessageFromOtherObject_Received(object sender, EventArgs arg)
    {
        //do some work
    }

    public void StartListeningToObject(MyClass obj)
    {
        obj.MessageReceived += MessageFromOtherObject_Received;
    }

    public void StopListeningToObject(MyClass obj)
    {
        obj.MessageReceived -= MessageFromOtherObject_Received;
    }
}
```

BTW, do not forget to trigger that event!

Comment: This doesn't explain why the OP's code isn't working.

Comment: Also, why does `MyClass` even have the two methods it has?  Neither of them are doing anything.  The only member of `MyClass` that does anything meaningful is the event declaration.

Comment: While you are right, and this may be what I will end up doing the other enswers helped me understand a bit better what I did wrong...

Comment: @Servy Well, as I said the class here is stripped to just the essential bits to illustrate the problem. Originally I felt that having explicit "Subscribe" and "Unsubscribe" methods would just make things more... well explicit :) It is probably also a notion that I've got when you still had to wrap your method names into the EventHandler object manually when you were attaching to an event and having a simple method which does that for you and you can just send the method name seemed like a good idea...

Comment: @bjavor The whole point of events in the first place is that it is an abstraction around a delegate instance that exposes two operations publicly for adding/removing handlers, so the `event` *is already doing exactly that*.  Creating methods to do that is strictly redundant.  And why you'd need to have an instance method that accepts another instance is beyond me; that's accomplishing nothing as one of the instances is strictly unnecessary. Your attempt to make the code "less confusing" is in fact making it more confusing and less functional. Just have an event that you add/remove handlers to.

Comment: @Servy Yes, I kinda agree with you now. I've learned something today :)

Comment: @Servy With "why do you have an instance method that accepts another instance" you mean the Start/Stop listening ones? The original idea was, that I would create create a common abstract BusinessObject base class which would provide some common facilities, like logging and log aggregation, and from which many other components would be derived. In the constructor of an object then you would potentially decide to aggregate message from any of the received components by calling "AggregateMessageFromComponent(c)" Which I thought would make for more "readable" code than the straight event syntax.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the target of the delegate that is signed up is really `eventHandler.Invoke` which is not really the target/method you want to delegate to. Then when you try to remove the handler, it is for a new delegate object's `Invoke` method, so they not are not considered equal and the original signup remains. You want to delegate to `MessageFromOtherObject_Received`. There are three options

- Directly do the add/remove in `Start`/`StopListeningToObject`
- Change the parameter type of `UnsubscribeFrom`/`SubscribeToMessages` to `EventHandler<EventArgs>`
- Create a delegate that has the correct target/method via

  ```
  var handler = (EventHandler<EventArgs>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(EventHandler<EventArgs>), eventHandler.Target, eventHandler.Method);
  this.MessageReceived += handler;
  ```

  with similar code in `UnsubscribeFromMessages` to remove the handler.

Comment: I've accepted Servy's answer because he's came first, but I found this to be very enlightening and educational as well. Many thanks!